# filter single parameter multiple values

Tags: powershell

I have the below code that gives me all users with enabled accounts, and description not like "Shared Account", "Service Account" or "Resource Account".

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(SamAccountName -notlike "nam-svc*") -and (SamAccountName -notlike "nam_svc*") -and (enabled -eq $true) -and (description -notlike "Shared Account*") -and (Description -notlike "service account*") -and (description -notlike "Resource Account*") } -Properties memberof
```

How can I simplify my code so that it is not as cluttered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-and` operator gives you free continuation across line breaks, so you could indent it like so:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {
    (enabled -eq $true) -and 
    (SamAccountName -notlike "nam-svc*") -and 
    (SamAccountName -notlike "nam_svc*") -and 
    (description -notlike "Shared Account*") -and 
    (Description -notlike "service account*") -and 
    (description -notlike "Resource Account*") } -Properties memberof
```

If you have many additional parameter arguments you want to pass to `Get-ADUser`, I suggest combining with [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting):

```
$ADUserParams = @{
    Filter = {
        (enabled -eq $true) -and 
        (SamAccountName -notlike "nam-svc*") -and 
        (SamAccountName -notlike "nam_svc*") -and 
        (description -notlike "Shared Account*") -and 
        (Description -notlike "service account*") -and 
        (description -notlike "Resource Account*")
    }
    Properties = 'memberof'
    SearchBase = "OU=target,DC=domain,DC=tld"
    SearchScope = 'subtree'
    Server = 'some-specific-DC.domain.tld'
}

Get-ADUser @ADUserParams
```